# TensorFlow - evaluate tensor value without providing the inputs

Tags: tensorflow

During training I want to decide if I want to get the value of a tensor based on the value of another tensor.

For example, if my loss value is > X I want to evaluate a summary tensor that outputs an image.

But I can't do `summary = sess.run([image_summary])` because then TensorFlow complains that I didn't provide the input feed_dict.

Is it possible to get the output value of a tensor without providing the input? Something like "calculate this summary tensor based on current values in the network"?

Comment: the image_summary variable in your graph is dependent on other variables to be calculated. If those variables aren’t supplied, TensorFlow can’t compute the value of image_summary.

Comment: Just provide the last input again, i.e. the input which caused the desired behaviour.

Comment: @GiuseppeMarra that would require redoing the whole calculation, I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: I need to check, but it should be possible to provide the last computed output as a placeholder. In case you can't, construct a second graph that takes the output and make the summary. The second graph will do only the indispensable operations.